# Python regex to parse/search (sql) text files

Tags: python, regex, multiline

Am trying to parse and validate a SQL query text file using Python regex.

- Search all *DELETE* statements from the file and notify  if there is no *WHARE* clause with it,
- Find all TEMP table CREATE statement and corresponding DROP table sql associated with it (usually at the bottom of file). Notify if not

Like this we need to validate the SQL query text file. The file might have comments as documentation for the following query section or some queries might be commented, which needs to be ignored.
Mostly SQL queries are multiline statements and ends with semicolon(;) or with a new line between two sql statements.

I am having hard time searching text like "DELETE" and get complete query statement for this and within this check whether WHERE clause exists. I am either getting only DELETE word or complete DELETE statements from comments as well.

Need help on this.

Comment: Why regex and not an SQL parser?

Comment: I dont want to validate SQL query. But validate rules, like all DELETE should have WHERE clause. ALL TEMP tables should be dropped or all STAGE tables should be in a STG schema only etc.

Comment: The rules you want to enforce are beyond regex capabilities, you need to implement your own logic. You could parse pieces of text with regex and then build on that, but using an SQL parser as suggested by @Selcuk would be some such easier, not for validating but for parsing the SQL query so you can apply your rules on it.

Comment: I do not want to alter the sql file. Just read the sql statements and check for rules and notify if not followed.
Eg. DELETE Emp_Data   <=== No WHERE clause found, notify through PRINT statement
DELETE Emp_Data WHERE Emp_Date > 'Condition';   <== Valid, as per rules. No need to notify

Comment: @RVandakar did you succeed in creating something for your need or ended up using a SQL parser? I am also looking for something similar but very basic. Just want to see if any SQL (text in a variable) has INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE.